# How to have the console echo (confirm) some commands?

Tags: console, bashrc

I have Ubuntu installed on several machines, and I'd like to replicate the behavior of the console I found on one of them in all my installs (they're all 12.04, 64 and 32 bits).

I installed Ubuntu Studio 12.04 ('lowlatency') several months ago, and maybe I did something back then, maybe I didn't, but I get a kind of "echo" of all the commands for which I find it's important to have one (like `rm`, `rmdir`, `ln`, `cp` and `mv`). I'm also prompted to confirm the `rm` type of commands, which I think is great even though a little annnoying sometimes... anyway, when I don't want to be bothered I just add a `-f` and all is well.

Here is an example with `cp`:

```
foo@bar: /tmp$ cp hello.txt world.txt
`hello.txt` -> `world.txt`
```

Same goes with `mv`. I'm fairly sure I didn't configure it myself, so I think it's a default behavior. I'd like to do the same on other machines, and why not even control the whole thing manually and decide which commands get an echo or not if possible. I suspect this has something to do with the `~/.bashrc` file, but that's about as far as I can get on my own.

How can I make some commands echo some feedback (like `ln`, `cp`, `mv`) and other prompt for confirmation (like `rm` and `rmdir`) in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `ln`, `cp`, `mv` and `rmdir` commands, you should use `-v` or `--verbose` option. From `man cp` and `man mv`:

> ```
>   -v, --verbose
>           explain what is being done
> ```

From `man ln`:

> ```
>    -v, --verbose
>           print name of each linked file
> ```

From `man rmdir`:

> ```
>   -v, --verbose
>           output a diagnostic for every directory processed
> ```

Note that you don't have any option to be prompted for confirmation when using `rmdir`, since `rmdir` remove empty directories. You can use `rm -d` instead with `-i` option (see below).

For `rm` command, you should use `-i` option. From `man rm`:

> ```
>    -i    prompt before every removal
> ```

Now, if you want that these commands to be executed with these options all the time in terminal, you can use aliases. So, add the following lines at the end of `~/.bashrc` file or in `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias cp='cp -v'
alias mv='mv -v'
alias ln='ln -v'
alias rmdir='rmdir -v' #or, better for what you asked: alias rmdir='rm -id'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed and accurate answer :) Some might have thrown a despising rtfm, and it's true the solution looks natural..!